# How can I convert a mongdb UUID() to a string?

Tags: mongodb, uuid

I want to generate a random UUID String, and insert it into mongo collection. How can I do it? I do not want a hex. I need the dashes.
I tried UUID().toString(), and it does not seem to work

Comment: I am assuming that you want to query this particular document using the uuid you give, is that right?

Comment: @abhinav, Yes. The value needs to be a guid string (36 characters), due to legacy data is in the format.

Comment: Unless someone can suggest a better answer, this is what I came up with. Apparently toString(), is casting it ot a string but leaving behind the `UUID()` method name wrapping, so my hack is.... `UUID().toString().split('UUID(').join("").split(')').join("")`

Answer (score 21):

The only way I was able to make this work was to use

```
UUID()
  .toString('hex')
  .replace(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/, '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5')
```

because I get `UUID().hex is not a function` error when I try `UUID().hex()` and `UUID().toString()` only returns gibberish.

Comment: This is the way to do it in Mogosh. All other methods resulted in encoding gibberish being returned.

Comment: Switched to the above after Studio 3T upgraded to use new shell `1.5.4`. Previously `UUID().toString().split('"')[1]` worked.

Answer (score 12):

According to your own comment, `UUID().toString()` includes the method name. Your solution includes the quotation marks. To get rid of those, you could use the following:

`UUID().toString().split('"')[1]`

Explanation:

- `UUID().toString()` will give a string containing `UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000")`.
- The `split('"')` will split the string, dividing by the quotation marks, into an array, which is `['UUID(', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', ')']`.
- `[1]` selects the second element from that array, which is your UUID as a string.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... For example, the operation `UUID().toString()` give me `l�X�N��� ��B`

Comment: @cactuschibre that's interesting. What shell are you using to get that response? Mine is mongo v4.0.3. It gives the following output:

    > UUID()
    UUID("a75cae57-a016-4142-ae1e-2197a093f763")
    > UUID().toString()
    UUID("9bc2a799-be68-46ac-bee3-53e5eae7f853")

Comment: I found it. `db.version()` gives me `3.4.2`. I managed to generate UUID() to string with `UUID().hex().toString()`.

Comment: @cactuschibre your comment will give something like `bf7151f190df40f4be6eb5bd13388be5` which is NOT in the format requested, i.e. missing the "-" dashes.

Answer (score -2):

To generate `uuid` in mongo db shell as a string, you need to call `uuid()` the following way. First import `uuid/v4` library using require statement (require statement will work on mongo shell as well).

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

print(uuid());

// output : "df5679ea-34bf-48c0-9e9c-8c92686a7f56"


db.users.insert({name: "username", uuid: uuid()});
```

Comment: The question here is about _reading_ a uuid document field and display as a string using some standard format, not about _writing_ a guid, which is trivial.