# How can I insert a mongdb UUID() as a string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, uuid

I want to generate a random UUID String, and insert it into mongo collection.

How can I do it?
I tried UUID().toString(), and return as shown below.

```
[
  {
    "result": "[object Object]"
  }
]
```

for UUID(), and return as shown below.

```
[
  {
    "result": {"$binary": {"base64": "DFFSHWQ0RnOnvnQmo69ypw==", "subType": "04"}}
  }
]
```

I hope it will be returned as below.

```
[
  {
    "result": "512f197f-90d6-4a07-8038-7f82eeb644f9"}
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a mongdb UUID() to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120094/how-can-i-convert-a-mongdb-uuid-to-a-string)

Comment: The result of running UUID().toString().split('"')[1] is the same as the result of running UUID().toString().

Comment: Look at the first answer in the link

Comment: In the new shell try `UUID().inspect().split('"')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has a built in UUID() function to generate one for you https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/UUID/
You should be able to grab the value of this an place it in a string field or just generate the UUID in your application if you have one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).